# How can I point my Spyder IDE to the path where all packages are installed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, pyinstaller, spyder

I had a massive crash today and lost a lot of work.  I couldn't start Spyder after many attempts; even tried 'spyder --reset'.  Nothing worked.  I decided to download a new version of Anaconda and start over.  Now, I'm trying to figure out why I can't run packages.

If I run this: `import pyodbc`

I get this: ModuleNotFoundError: `No module named 'pyodbc'`

So, I go to the command prompt to pip install pyodbc...and apparently it's already installed...

[image]

When I navigate to that path, I can see the package

[image]

...but Spyder is still telling me it's not installed.  What's an easy fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had similar crash problems on Windows 10, what I learned is that I had several non-conda versions of python on my PC, and I used 'pip install' in my environments so it messed up with conda packages and it stop working.

What I did is that I uninstalled anaconda and non-conda python, cleaned up registry from python mentions, installed fresh new miniconda, and 'conda install spyder' in the new env, conda have created new folder

> C:\Users\~~~\**.spyder-py3**\

Inside of it I found "spyder.ini" file, where incorrect variable was set:

> "spyder_pythonpath  = "

I changed it from

> ['C:\Users\~~~\**anaconda3**\pkgs',
> 'C:\Users\~~~\**anaconda3**\envs']

to

> ['C:\Users\~~~\**miniconda3**\pkgs',
> 'C:\Users\~~~\**miniconda3**\envs']

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am back in business now. Big help!!

Answer (score 0):

**Please Upvote it take so much time**
First open Spyder and click Tools --> Open command prompt.

[image]

You should see the Command Window appear in the bottom right of your screen.

[image]

Here we install the Python package seaborn as an example.

*# In the command line, type pip install seaborn
C:\Users\your_username\Documents\Python Scripts>pip install seaborn*

This will install seaborn on your machine.

[image]
Note:

To upgrade the pip version on Windows, type python -m pip install --upgrade pip on the command line.
[image]

*On Windows, all of your Python packages can be found in the directory of C:\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages if you use the default path when you install Anaconda.
To upgrade the pip version on OS X, type pip install --upgrade pip on the command line.*

Comment: Thanks, but under Tools, I don't have an option to 'Open Command Prompt'.  It looks like you are using Python 2.7; I have 3.8.  Maybe that's why.  Not sure.

Comment: ouh,yup thats true

Answer (score 0):

I run tinypeen when im doing installs, feedback has been surprisingly positive

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).